# Laravel Query Builder Joins

Tags: mysql, laravel

Good afternoon pips, I would like to ask for your help.

Could you please help me apply this query into the Laravel Query Builder. I only know how to query into the database using raw query.

Query:

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, users.id as userID, bookmarks.id, 
products.title, products.price, products.id AS productID FROM users,
products, bookmarks WHERE bookmarks.user_id = $user_id AND products.id = 
bookmarks.product_id AND users.id = products.user_id;
```

Thank you for those people that would help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this Laravel Query.

```
$response = DB::table('users as u')->select(
    'u.id as userId',
    'u.first_name',
    'u.last_name',
    'b.id as bookmarkId',
    'p.id as productId',`enter code here`
    'p.title',
    'p.price'
)
->leftjoin('bookmarks as b', 'b.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
->leftjoin('products as p', 'p.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
->where('u.id', $userId)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $result = DB::select(DB::raw('custom_query'));
   $user_name = $result[0]->first_name.' '.$result[0]->last_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, users.id as userID,
>   bookmarks.id,  products.title, products.price, products.id AS
>   productID FROM users, products, bookmarks WHERE bookmarks.user_id =
>   $user_id AND products.id =  bookmarks.product_id AND users.id =
>   products.user_id;

You can use the eloquent with method and just access the relations but if you want the laravel query method. You can use the DB::raw to have your own raw query.

```
DB::select(DB::raw("Select a.first_name, a.last_name, a.id as user_id, b.id, c.title, c.price, c.id from users as a INNER JOIN bookmarks as b on b.user_id = $user_id INNER JOIN Products as c on c.id = b.product_id where  user_id = c.user_id"));
```

This is just an example, it's still up to you on how you manipulate your queries.

Love,
Poop